Blender Python [Adding Nodes Issue]
I am wondering as to why it's showing me this python tooltip:

And not this:

It's the same tooltip message for every shader, it should show the different names.
It shows bpy.ops.node.add_node(use_transform....), but it's supposed to show bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeValToRGB") it doesn't show the name.

Hello and welcome to BSE. You mean you don't like it to show Python tooltips? You can disable it in Edit > Preferences > Interface > Python Tooltips

No, it shows bpy.ops.node.add_node(use_transform....), but it's supposed to show bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeValToRGB") it doesn't show the name.

Hello. It's not an error, it's an update from the python API. Basically, from one Blender's version to another, Python API may change, and so it may be the same for some operators and python tooltips. I recommend you to check the official API doc to see the difference for this item.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.node.html

What Blender version are you using ? I use 4.1 and it shows but parameters in the tooltip.

Yes, Blender v4.0 and below will show the truncated tooltip

and
Blender v4.1 and above will show the full tooltip

